# Error with Table of Contents in Arabic template

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, arabic

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mathbook_arabic}
 
 %\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Arial}
   \addto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{الفهرس}}
  
  % \newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic]{Arial}
 
\usepackage{listings}
 \usepackage{mathrsfs}
 
 
 
  
  
\definecolor{bleu}{cmyk}{0.59,0.11,0,0.59}
\definecolor{vert}{cmyk}{0.78,0,0.74,0.45}
       
 
\begin{document}

 
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Intro}
some textes 
\chapter{ch1}


  
  
  
 
  
  
     
 
 
 \end{document}
```

the error when i compile this  is

> File ended while scanning use of @dottedtocline.
>
> \par
> l.68 \tableofcontents

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Could you trim this down to the minimal Arabic file that you think should compile but doesn't?  Something like `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} الفهرس \end{document}`.

Comment: @Teepeemm ok done

Comment: the error is in the `.toc` file so start by deleting that and the `.aux` file.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't show the table of contents so when I compile again the error message appears again. Thanks

Comment: Where can we find the source of `mathbook_arabic.cls`? Is it a requirement, or could we substitute a different template? Are you able to edit it?

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: @Davislor 
yeah  this is the source code https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/nice-arabic-book-template/qttfgxhqbwkc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for linking to the template on Overleaf.  I can’t reproduce your bug on TeX Live 2020, although I do get a different one: `\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt` on line 107 of `mathbook_arabic.sty` should be `\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf`.  It then re-declares `\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt` on the next line.  Older versions of `fontspec` allowed this, but modern ones flag it as a bug.

That template has a lot of stuff in it that’s specific to the book it was written for, and has gotten a little out of date.  If you’re free to use whatever template you want, I would suggest you start with something like this, and modify it as necessary.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book} % Or article, scrbook, etc.
\tracinglostchars=2 % Warn if the current font does not have a character.

%% The previous sample you were using loaded the cmyk color space and manually
%% declared color names in French.  This loads the standard color names used in
%% CSS, SVGs and HTML, e.g. Blue and DarkCyan.  You can add HTML to allow hex
%% values.
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

%% Requires LuaHBTeX, or LuaLaTeX from 2020 or later.
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=sectioning]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{microtype}

%% You will certainly want to set more options than this, either here or with
%% \hypersetup.
\usepackage[unicode,
            colorlinks]{hyperref}

%% Can substitute import=ar-DZ, import=ar-MA or import=ar-SY for import.
%% To change the numbers from Western to localized, add the maparabic option.
%% Can also change other counters, e.g. alph=alphabetic, Alph=abjad.
\babelprovide[import, main, onchar=ids fonts]{arabic}
\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{english}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX, Renderer=HarfBuzz}

%% You can change these to your fonts of choice.

\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0, Ligatures=Common, Script=Default, Language=Default]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}
          {Amiri}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures=Common, Script=Default, Language=Default]{Libertinus Sans}
\babelfont[arabic]{sf}
          [Language=Default]{Noto Sans Arabic}
\babelfont{tt}
          [Script=Default, Language=Default]{Libertinus Mono}
\babelfont[arabic]{tt}
          {ALM Fixed}

\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\babeltags{english=english}
%% \babeltags would fail to redefine \arabic, so provide `\textArabic`, etc.
%% You are unlikely to need them, because babel will switch to Arabic whenever
%% you use the Arabic script.
\babeltags{Arabic=arabic}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}

للُّغَة العَرَبِيّة هي أكثر اللغات السامية تحدثاً، وإحدى أكثر اللغات انتشاراً في العالم، يتحدثها أكثر من 467 مليون نسمة،

\begin{english}
Arabic (اَلْعَرَبِيَّةُ, al-ʿarabiyyah, [al ʕaraˈbijːa] or عَرَبِيّ‎, ʿarabīy, [ˈʕarabiː]
or [ʕaraˈbij]) is a Semitic language that first emerged in the 1st to 4th
centuries CE.
\end{english}

\end{document}
```

This version of the template will automatically switch to English whenever you type in the Latin script and Arabic whenever you type in the Arabic script.  It does use one language tag in this example, which is because the IPA symbols in the source I copy-pasted are neither, but they should display left-to-right in the English font.  It would be possible to tell Babel to consider them English.  You could have added redefinitions for every missing character, like

```
\babelcharproperty{`ʕ}{locale}{english}
```

The main fonts I selected were Khaled Hosny’s Amiri and Libertinus Sans, both of which are based on earlier designs and complement each other very well.

You can change these to your fonts of choice.  For example, if you have the new version of Arial distributed with Windows 10 instead of the old one that still ships with some OSes, you can replace `\babelfont{sf}` and the three lines after it with `\babelfont{sf}{Arial}`.  The font will automatically scale and select the correct `Script` and `Language` OpenType features.  (Actually, the `Language=` feature will give you spurious warnings, so you can use `\babelfont{sf}[Language=Default]{Arial}` to suppress them.)

For math, I loaded his Libertinus Math in `unicode-math`.  This means you will not need (and should not use) any legacy math font packages such as `amssymb`.  It supports `\boldmath` and `\boldsymbol`.  If that isn’t what you want, you can instead replace `\usepackage{unicode-math)` and the `\setmathfont` line with

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}
```

I don’t change the default formats of the pages, titles, chapters, table of contents or so on, but you can do this with your packages of choice, such as `tocloft` and `fancyhdr`.

Comment: Thanks 
so can i use a template in french and translate it to arabic easily ?

Comment: @Nour-EddineRahmani I’m not sure I understand your question. What kind of “template in French?”

Comment: the problem I don't have time to create a new style, that's why I am looking for a template, I got the original template in french and I m trying with to make it arabic by my own

Comment: @Nour-EddineRahmani French and Arabic are going to be different enough that I can’t guarantee everything will necessarily work.I don’t have a book template in Arabic for you, but what I posted is how I would start, and you can add formatting commands and packages to that if you need them.

Comment: understood thanks  Sir Davislor

Comment: how to tell babel to consider something English?

Comment: @Nour-EddineRahmani Excuse me, that code sample is incorrect and needs a backtick. I added a fixed version to the answer.

Comment: one last thing how to reverse numbring of newtheorem like \newtheorem{defi}{definition}