# Some arabic chars appear as boxes with some fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, arabic

When I try to use a font like `AGA Dimnah Regular`, all letters appear as empty boxes.

[image]

I tried opening the file in a font editing software. it appears that AGA Dimnah is using some weird special glyphs instead of using the defined ones, but the browser has no issue rendering this font, neither does MS Word.

first glyph appears at U+f201, which is empty
but I also see some other interesting glyphs, such as this one

[image: weird glyph]

which probably is the combination of three letters: لمحـ

is there any package that's used to render such fonts?

some extra info:
I import the font this way:

```
\newfontfamily\dimnah{AGA Dimnah Regular}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\dimnah[Script=Arabic]{AGA Dimnah Regular}
\begin{document}
\dimnah{الحمد لله رب العالمين}
\end{document}
```

would show:

[image: another example]

after adding \tracinglost chars, here's the output I'm getting from my terminal:
https://pastebin.com/GJxmpNeK

more info will be added if needed.

Comment: Could you give a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that reproduces the bug? Without one, we can’t tell where the problem is.

Comment: A good first step to diagnosing the error would be to add the command `\tracinglostchars=2` near the top of your document. This will print a warning message on the console when a font is missing a character, telling you which character it was looking for. Otherwise, the warning will silently be added to the `.log` file.

Comment: Does the document compile if you load a different font, such as Amiri?

Comment: Loading `polyglossia` with `\newfontfamily\arabicfont{AGA Dimnah}[Script=Arabic, Language=Arabic, Scale=MatchLowercase]` might work, or `babel` with `\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{AGA Dimnah}`.

Comment: @Davislor yessir

Comment: @Davislor I tried both polyglossia and babel solutions, neither worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font you’re using is from 1994 and encoded in Windows codepage 1256, which is obsolete.  You will need to use a Unicode font in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Khaled Hosny’s Amiri is an excellent one that also has good complements in his Libertinus and Libertinus Math fonts.  [Here is an example of a template I made using it.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562327/error-with-table-of-contents-in-arabic-template)  All the fonts it uses should be in your TeX distribution, except possibly [Noto Sans Arabic.](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-arab)

Comment: Thank you for the info Davislor, I didn't know about this encoding, but unfortunately, I have to use AGA Dimnah Regular because I'm trying to write a worksheet and this font is needed in order to mimic the teacher's worksheet. is there a way to use this encoding in latex or even lualatex? other than that, I might try the Amiri font and I think it will look good

Comment: @abbas.1 Not without a lot of effort. You might attempt to politely inform your teacher that their font is incompatible with modern software, you might ask if you can use another font, or since you say it works in Word, you might use Office’s Equation Editor.

Comment: @abbas.1 I have a faint suspicion that someone who’s been doing things a particular way for more than twenty-five years and instructs all their students to also do things that particular way is likely to be set in their ways, but you know the person and I don’t. Maybe this is the first time it caused any problems.

Comment: @abbas.1 Is there a look-alike font out there they would accept?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thank you so much. The Amiri font looks fantastic and the teacher is ok with it. I think I'm going to take a look at luatex as it might have some kind of support to such font types or at least look for a tool that converts cp-1256 to utf8. Again thank you and sorry about the late response.

Comment: @abbas.1 I was in no hurry. :) As for converting, a text editor should be able to open the file in the 8-bit encoding and save a copy as UTF-8. There's also the command-line program `iconv`.

Comment: thank you for the help man, much appreciated.